# php and wrong output with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, utf-8

I am using php in order to read a .txt file which contains any kind of characters.
When I use the php function, utf8_decode() characters such as éàêô... are correctly recognized but chinese characters are displayed as ????.
And when I don't use utf8_decode() the echo output of a chinese character is something like åŒ—äº¬å. What is stranged is that on the source code of the generated webpage the chinese characters are corectly displayed.

How can I do to have a correct output ?

I use the fgets function to creat a variable $buffer to read into the .txt file and then :

```
$buffer = explode(" ", $buffer);

foreach($buffer as $word){
    //$word=utf8_decode($word);
    echo "$word \n";
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Sentences. We use them. You don't.

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: Or give more details, code, etc.

Comment: Hi, this needs more information - what code you are using, what output encoding you have on your page, and so on. Also check out the link eggyal points out, it's good basic reading on the topic of character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mb_string's different functions - http://php.net/mb_string